# postgres different types of update

Tags: postgresql

From PostgreSQL documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) it says:

> Update contact names in an accounts table to match the currently
> assigned salespeople:
>
> ```
> UPDATE accounts SET (contact_first_name, contact_last_name) =
>     (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees
>      WHERE employees.id = accounts.sales_person);
> ```
>
> A similar result could be accomplished with a join:
>
> ```
> UPDATE accounts SET contact_first_name = first_name,
>                     contact_last_name = last_name
>   FROM employees WHERE employees.id = accounts.sales_person;
> ```
>
> However, the second query may give unexpected results if employees.id
> is not a unique key, whereas the first query is guaranteed to raise an
> error if there are multiple id matches. Also, if there is no match for
> a particular accounts.sales_person entry, the first query will set the
> corresponding name fields to NULL, whereas the second query will not
> update that row at all.

By second query I think they mean this:

```
UPDATE accounts SET contact_first_name = first_name,
                    contact_last_name = last_name
  FROM employees WHERE employees.id = accounts.sales_person;
```

Well it turns out I used this kind of query , much like the first one:

```
UPDATE EVERGREEN
SET (INTENDED_REMEDIATION_DATE,
                        REMEDIATION_TYPE,
                        REMARK) =
    (SELECT "Intended Remediation Date"::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE,
            "Remediation Type",
            "Remark"
        FROM PERRY
        WHERE PERRY.UUID::UUID = EVERGREEN.UUID);
```

And I got updated for the entries I desired, but all the rest was set to NULL. Why ? this is exactly like the first query

Comment: The first query (and your query) updates *all* rows in the table to update. There is no `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` statement. And what is happening does exactly follow their explanation: "*if there is no match for a particular accounts.sales_person entry, the first query will set the corresponding name fields to NULL*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see your query first:

```
UPDATE EVERGREEN
SET (INTENDED_REMEDIATION_DATE,
                        REMEDIATION_TYPE,
                        REMARK) =
    (SELECT "Intended Remediation Date"::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE,
            "Remediation Type",
            "Remark"
        FROM PERRY
        WHERE PERRY.UUID::UUID = EVERGREEN.UUID);
```

Let's see what happens:

- it updates **all records** inside `EVERGREEN`
- to the three selected values from `PERRY`
- where `UUID` values are matching

You apparently expected the query to update only the records that had a pair in the subquery and error out if there are more than one matches. Before we proceed with the first expectation, let's first clarify the second. Your query does not error out because the subquery yields a single result **at most** for each `EVERGREEN` record, because your matching criteria is being done by `UUID`, which turned out to be unique in your test, but in order to guarantee its uniqueness, you can create a unique constraint. Now, let's understand the first expectation and let's quote from the docs again for this purpose:

> However, the second query may give unexpected results if employees.id is not a unique key, whereas the first query is guaranteed to raise an error if there are multiple id matches. Also, if there is no match for a particular accounts.sales_person entry, the first query will set the corresponding name fields to NULL, whereas the second query will not update that row at all.

Points to make:

1. The second query may give unexpected results if employeed.id is not a unique key, that is, if there are multiple matches in the subquery, then the update will end up updating the values to the last processed match (for the second query), which is why it may yield unexpected results, because you might expect they to end up having the value of a match, but they lack it, but in this case, given the fact that the matching criteria is unique with the data you have (but there is no guarantee for that to be true in the future as well), no such confusion can happen for the second query
2. The first query would error out if there were two matches for any of the records, but since you have one match at most, this does not apply here
3. If there are no matches for some records (your case), then the first query will set the values to `null`, whereas, the second query would not update them at all

How to solve the issue:

- you may change your `update` so it will use joins and filter out the records you are not interested about, because you do not have to worry about duplicate results, given the fact that you filter by `UUID`
- or, you could add a where clause to your query to filter out any record that may be less than interesting for your purpose

Since you expected unmatched records to be left intact, to me it's quite clear that a simple refactor of your `update` to use join instead of subselect will work out well for you, that is, your query should look more like the second query rather than the first query.

Comment: Using `UUID` does not mean that the values will be unique. Only a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column will guarantee that.

Comment: @Bergi this is why I used the term "quite" unique, that is, they are much more likely to be unique than, say, a two-valued column. But thanks for the comment, I will adjust this in the answer.

Comment: @Bergi made some adjustments accordingly. Thanks!